# passing mouse clicks to line algorithm

Tags: c#

I wrote bresenham algorithm for

> `0<Angular coefficient<1`

I don't know much about **graphics** in C#,I realized that for drawing **pixles** I can use the function **Fillrectangel** with coordinate 1,1

I wanted to write my code then when clicking the mouse on panel and in two positions draw me a line from **x0,y0 to xEnd,yEnd**

so here is my code which has exception

[image]

*Null reference exception was unhandled
object reference not set to an instance of the object*
this exception is in line  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(grad1), x, y, 1, 1);

**I think the problem is that object e is Null and I should new it but how?**

How can I correct my code so as to draw Line?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                Line l=new Line();
                l.LineBres(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);

            }
        }
    }
    public class Line
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e;
        Color grad1 = Color.FromArgb(165, 194, 245);
        public void LineBres(int x0, int y0, int xEnd, int yEnd)
        {
            int dx = xEnd - x0;
            int dy = yEnd = y0;
            int p = 2 * dy - dx;
            int twoDy = 2 * dy;
            int twoDyMinusDx = 2 * (dy - dx);
            int x, y;
            if (x0 > xEnd)
            {
                x = xEnd;
                y = yEnd;
                xEnd = x0;
            }
            else
            {
                x = x0;
                y = y0;
            }

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(grad1), x, y, 1, 1);
            while (x < xEnd)
            {
                x++;
                if (p < 0)
                    p += twoDy;
                else
                {
                    y++;
                    p += twoDyMinusDx;
                }
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(grad1), x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you write the exception message?

Comment: instead asking why you have exception please write what exception you getting(message and/or stacktrace)

Comment: I think I should new this line System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e but how!? I don't know about e what it will take as input after newing? the problem is that e is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to change:

Add mouse click event for panel and change your Line code a bit - remove `System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e;` and pass Graphics of panel with `panel1.CreateGraphics();`. Here is the code:

```
private int firstX, firstY;//store coordinates of first click
private bool firstClick = true;
private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (firstClick)
    {
        firstX = e.X;
        firstY = e.Y;
        firstClick = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Line l = new Line();
        l.LineBres(firstX, firstY, e.X, e.Y, panel1.CreateGraphics());
        firstClick = true;
    }
}

public class Line
{
    private Color grad1 = Color.FromArgb(165, 194, 245);

    public void LineBres(int x0, int y0, int xEnd, int yEnd, Graphics e)
    {
        int dx = xEnd - x0;
        int dy = yEnd = y0;
        int p = 2*dy - dx;
        int twoDy = 2*dy;
        int twoDyMinusDx = 2*(dy - dx);
        int x, y;
        if (x0 > xEnd)
        {
            x = xEnd;
            y = yEnd;
            xEnd = x0;
        }
        else
        {
            x = x0;
            y = y0;
        }

        e.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(grad1), x, y, 1, 1);
        while (x < xEnd)
        {
            x++;
            if (p < 0)
                p += twoDy;
            else
            {
                y++;
                p += twoDyMinusDx;
            }
            e.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(grad1), x, y, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: select panel, in Properties window there is button events(with lightning symbol) after you click it you will get list of available controls events. Find MouseClick line and double click that line and you will have mouse click event